# Connect AVD from host to client (VMWARE)

Tags: android, ubuntu, virtual-machine, adt

I'm using a VM with Ubuntu for development (react-native), on a Windows 10 Host.

I read that it is not possible to run AVD on a VM, so my intention was to run the AVD on Windows, and somehow connect it to the VM through ADB (I can connect my personal device by connecting it via USB).

Is there anyway to do this?
Is there anyway to debug without an actual device on a VM?

Thanks

Comment: I am interested in this as well, please let me know if you ever find the answer to this.